# Creating a column in a dataframe with values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
A B A B B A B B
```

It's only one row and each column has one letter. I wanna take these letters, **two by two** and insert them in another dataframe, as follows:

```
V1 V2 V3
X AB F
Y AB G
Z BA H
W BB I
```

How should I proceed? Maybe turn the first dataframe into a vector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get V1 and V3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue where `V1` and `V3` come from, but the code below can help you produce `V2`

```
do.call(rbind,
  Map(function(x) do.call(paste0,x),
  split.default(df1,ceiling(seq_along(df1)/2)))
)
```

which gives

```
  [,1]
1 "AB"
2 "AB"
3 "BA"
4 "BB"
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(V1 = "A", V2 = "B", V3 = "A", V4 = "B", V5 = "B", 
    V6 = "A", V7 = "B", V8 = "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! V1 and V3 were just intended to show there are other columns in the dataframe. I'm sorry about the confusion, I'm not used to ask questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more long-winded way of doing this.

```
xy <- structure(list(V1 = "A", V2 = "B", V3 = "A", V4 = "B", V5 = "B", 
               V6 = "A", V7 = "B", V8 = "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                  -1L))
xy <- unlist(xy)  # split doesn't work on data.frames

# Make sure that length of xy is divisible by 2.
stopifnot((length(xy) %% 2) == 0)

tosplit <- rep(1:(length(xy) / 2), each = 2)
tosplit <- factor(tosplit)

xy <- split(xy, f = tosplit)
xy <- lapply(xy, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
xy <- unlist(xy)
xy

   1    2    3    4 
"AB" "AB" "BA" "BB"
```

This can easily be manipulated into a data.frame of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

We can also convert to a `matrix` of two columns and then do the `paste`

```
do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
#[1] "AB" "AB" "BA" "BB"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = "A", V2 = "B", V3 = "A", V4 = "B", V5 = "B", 
    V6 = "A", V7 = "B", V8 = "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```